# Access media from offline storage after sending it to server like whatsapp

Tags: android, local-storage, media

**What I Want**

I want the media files to be sent to server , once it is sent then read the media file from the local storage (There can be any number of images like whatsapp)

**My problems**

How do I recognise the images  that has been delete from offline storage.

**In Short I wanted to develop and app that works even in offline-mode like whatsapp (for mediafiles , chats text)**

**If any tutorials please help me to get started**

Comment: `I want the media files to be sent to server`.  Which media files?  `once it is sent then read the media file from the local storage `. What has that to do with being sent or not? If they are in local storage you can read them already before sending. Strange story.

Answer (score 0):

Store media **absolute path on local** in sqlite and with status **isOnline** true or false.
Once media is sent to server update its status **isOnline** to **true**.
Now show media by **path** in db when **isOnline** is false.

If file is deleted, you will get **FileNotFoundException** and handle it by fetching from server again or place holder image like whatsapp.